# Port Forwarding for Playstation TV

Tags: ps4, playstation-tv

I really want my PSTV to work well and I can't seem to find any instructions online in regard to port forwarding or anything else that will improve my connection. I have my PS4 connected with a LAN cable and the PSTV will be used via WiFi. Any help or information would be appreciated.

Comment: No port forwarding should be required; it's all internal, so there's no need to get it through a firewall.  Is there a problem you're having with the PS TV?

Comment: @Frank Yeah it just loses connection too frequently or lags too hard. I also can't get a signal at all from one of my two rooms I've tested it on, but my Vita can remote play perfectly from both locations.

Comment: That has less to do with port forwarding, and more with where your wifi is located.  I wouldn't be surprised if the wifi in the PS TV is slightly weaker than the Vita itself.

Comment: @Frank I guess that is the case. Hopefully a firmware update will help out eventually. Thanks for the input.

Comment: A firmware update isn't going to help what is essentially a hardware issue.  The PS TV has a network port, so I'd recommend giving it a wired connection, and see what happens.  Either that, or move your wifi access point closer to where you're losing connection.

Answer (score 1):

As the PS TV works over Wifi, no port-forwarding is required to connect to the PS4. What you need to do is possibly connect the PS TV using ethernet to improve the connection. If you cannot connect the PS TV to Ethernet, try using a Wifi booster to increase the signal.

You can also try enabling "Direct Connection" for Remote Play on the PS4 and see if that makes a difference to your connection. The only port forwarding you may need to do is on the PS4, for certain online games.